# Security.addProvider is not working with tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, bouncycastle

My envvironment is JDK7, Tomcat7, Maven, Spring4

and I want to use AES/GCM cryto.

so I added bcprov-jdk15on 1.59 to my maven dependencies

and in method I wrote

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
```

As I packaged this project to WAR and deployed to tomcat

then **'no such algorithm AES/GCM/NoPadding'** error displayed.

but I made an independent class with a static main method in this project and executed a class to 'Run as a Java application', then it worked.

I copied bcprov-jdk15on.jar to JDK7's jre/lib/ext directory and modified security policy file and added Security provider on it. then it worked properly even on Tomcat.

It seems like addProvider method is not working properly. How can I use bouncycastle provider and AES/GCM crypto algorithm without adding external jar to jre/lib/ext directory?

Comment: Have you checked that your .war  actually contained the bouncycastle file?

Comment: There is an issue with with Java7 above version21. Maybe this helps: [Security.addProvider with JDK 7 update 21](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2532444)

Comment: I checked it and it contained. if bouncycastle file was not on it, import class or new BouncyCastleProvider() would be failed. but it didn't. "BC" provider is exist but AES/GCM algorithm is missing just with Tomcat.

Comment: thanks a lot @AndreAlbert, I'll try that.

Comment: Did you install the unlimited policy files in the JVM? I am not sure if AES/GCM is restricted when you install the provider dinamically. See http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation